# How to trigger plugin in MS Dynamic CRM on N:N relationships?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want trigger MS Dynamic CRM plugin in N:N(many to many) relationships?

When user add or remove row from N:N relationship, then exposed my plugin.

It's possible, and how if it's?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Depends on your CRM version. General idea is registering plugin for Associate/Disassociate events. For CRM 4.0 it is described [here](http://matthewdmead.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/registering-plugins-on-many-to-many-relationships-crm-4-0/). How to do this in CRM 2011 you can read [here](http://orwin.ca/2011/07/05/crm-2011-plugin-triggering-off-associate-message/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. By Using Associate and Disassociate messages in Plugin Registration Tool. if you want to add a record in any entity by using N:N Relationship the message should be Associate, primary/secondary entities should be set it as **null** then it will fire and for removing a record you can do by using Disassociate message.